# SCTP - Protocol Unreachable Error

Tags: linux, tcp, sctp

I am working on basic SCTP message exchange (Novice in SCTP) and getting the "ICMP Protocol Unreachable Error".

I am using two linux machines 'A' (Source) and 'B' (Destination). In B machine sipp tool is listening over SCTP on 5080 port (This is verified using netstat).

Firstly machine B is reachable from my machine A, i must not get "Destination Unreachable|Host Unreachable". Secondly netstat has verified that listening port is 5080 so i must not get "Port Unreachable" also.

Now i am sending INIT from A (28232 port) to B (5080 port). Interestingly i am getting "ICMP - Protocol Unreachable" ? I am not able to co-relate this ICMP error.

After searching the internet i found few posts (outside stackoverflow) saying "ICMP Protocol Unreachable error and SCTP connect have some race condition". I am not able to locate any such issue in linux kernel website.

I am using RHEL machine with kernel version 3.10.0-327.28.2.el7.x86_64 .

Can someone help me in explaining the expected behavior.

Sudhansu

Answer (score 0):

From the Kernel Version you have shared,

You seem to be running RHEL 7.2

You might need to check if there is a firewall firewall is on..(SCTP is not allowed by default on the Linux firewall)

try

1:stopping the firewall and see if the error clears

2:If the error clears on the point 1 above then you can allow the specific SCTP port on your firewall and it should work without an problem.

let me know if this one works or if you get stuck at any point.